# Backspace in Terminal Vim (Cygwin)

Tags: windows, vim, terminal, cygwin

I'm running a default cygwin install on Windows 8 and can not get the Backspace key to delete characters - I'm expecting the character to be overwritten with a blank when I backspace.

I've tried

```
set backspace=2 "
set backspace=indent,eol,start
:fixdel
```

nothing seems to work.

Both
`:verbose imap <BS>` 
and
`:verbose imap ^H` 
return
`No mapping found`

Comment: Does Vim pick up the backspace at all? I use `:echo getchar()` as a sanity check for this sort of thing. Try running that command and pressing a key -- space or something -- on your keyboard. You should get a number (the key code) to appear. What happens if you do that and press backspace?

Comment: Yes, the cursor does move back. And when you exit insert mode, the characters are removed from view. When trying the :echo getchar() I get the following error "E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version"

Comment: so to be clear. I enter insert mode .. type 123456 ... hit backspace 3 times. This moves the cursor back 3 spaces. When I then his ESC to exit insert mode, characters 456 are removed .. I'd like them be remove while I'm in insert mode.

Comment: What really is happening there is that the characters are getting removed, but your cygwin terminal isn't getting refreshed. Don't really know how to solve that. If you use gvim, though, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, but really looking for a solution that'll work in vim.

Comment: Same thing here, Windows XP, Vim 7.3.

Comment: If the answer below worked, you should accept it!

Answer (score 21):

Add these settings together:

```
:set nocompatible
:set backspace=2
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I’ve experienced a weird behavior in a Cygwin installation on Windows 7. When pressing the backspace key Cygwin, interprets it as a space.

Luckily, the problem is rather easy to fix. The easiest way (which did not work everytime while testing) is to simply reinstall terminfo and termcap via setup.exe, as mentioned here: Backspace does not work in Cygwin. If you don’t have termcap installed install it but make sure to reinstall terminfo properly too. At best this is all you need to do to get your backspace back again.

If not, you might need to remove .bashrc from your home folder, e.g. /cygwin/home/you/.bashrc. Then, just to make sure reinstall terminfo and termcap again. This always worked for me.

Enjoy your backspace :)

Answer (score 0):

In command mode, have you considered just pressing an upper case 'X' in lieu of a backspace?  This will remove one character to the left, very similar to the backspace behavior you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was unable to erase anything using backspace and when using the arrow button I got characters like ABCD.

I followed the below link and created ".virc" which fixed it and now I am able to use it. I deleted the ".vimrc" which was of no use.

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-fix-the-annoying-arrow-key-and-backspace-problem-in-Cygwin

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this for myself and thought I might have a correct answer for you:

```
type -a vim
```

This revealed to me that vim was an alias to vi -N. If you see that then go to your setup-x86_64.exe (Cywgin setup, maybe different for example on 32 bit systems) and install the full Vim package.

Just a disclaimer: I get the impression that this is a symptom with more than a few root causes. Because this question has been open 5 years and still doesn't have an accepted answer I'm adding mine.

Answer (score -1):

I used this command  `:set nocp`(and press enter) in the vi command line.
But, you will need to do this every time you start vi.